# Webgl not running in chromium(ubuntu) AWS G2 instances with NVIDIA GRID K520

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, webgl, nvidia, chromium

I am getting the following errors when trying to run webgl contents with chromium on AWS G2 instances with NVIDIA GRID K520

```
ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(260): Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(133): Failed to launch GPU process.THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
```

I have installed the nvidia drivers , and set flags like 
`"--ignore-gpu-blacklist,--enable-webgl"` but still getting errors .

Comment: hey Joshan, I'm encountering the same issue here using chrome version 55... did you manage to work around this issue?

Comment: Same problem. Can't make chrome to enable webgl in ec2 instance